# nginx: Redirect to index.html if a given URI points to an existing directory

Tags: nginx

Let's say user enters `http://mysite.com/css` in the browser. I want to redirect to index.html if the URI, `css` in this case, is a directory that exists in the server root. To see it in action, after a request is handled, the URL in the address bar should remain as is (e.g. `http://mysite.com/css`), but the contents of index.html is served instead of showing the structure of the directory.

Here is what I have tried. Note that `/login` and `/share` are not directories nor files in my server root. There are just rewrite rules for `/php/login.php` and `/php/share.php`.

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
}

location = /css {
    # redirects to index.html, but removes css from URL,
    # i.e. http://mydomain.com/css -> http://mydomain.com
    rewrite ^(.+)$ /index.html/css break;
}

location = /php {
    rewrite ^(.+)$ /index.html/php break;
}

location ^~ /login/ {
    rewrite ^/login/(.+)$ /php/login.php?url=$1 last;
}

location ^~ /share/ {
    rewrite ^/share/(.+)$ /php/share.php?url=$1 last;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    # NOTE: You should have "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" in php.ini

    # With php5-cgi alone:
    #fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    # With php5-fpm:
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
}
```

There are two directories `css` and `js` in my server root. With this configuration, a request to `http://mydomain.com/css` or `http://mydomain.com/php` redirects to `http://mydomain.com`. That is fine, but the URI is dropped. How can I do that?

I'm also curious how to generalize the behaviour for any number of directories in the server root. I probably need to use `if` to check if a requested URI is a directory, but I [read](http://wiki.nginx.org/IfIsEvil) over and over that `if` must be avoided whenever possible. For only 2 directories, having separate location blocks should be more efficient, I guess?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had an error in my code... After fixing it now 'http://mydomain.com/css' serves contents from index.html. I was using `&` instead of `$` in the regular expression...